# Print the report range - VBA is not executed normally

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to print the report range? The following VBA is not executed normally, I hope you can give me your advice, thank you!

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "ABC", acViewPreview, "", "[ID]=" & ProjectID, acNormal
DoCmd.PrintOut PrintRange:=acPages, PageFrom:=1, PageTo:=2**
```

The ACCESS report has limited page printing, and when the above VBA is executed, an error occurs, and two different prints appear consecutively

Comment: You must tell us exactly what the error said. And should tell us how the "different prints" differ.

Comment: until then check your assumptions, simplify this command until it works.  Also check your printing options, margins and such.  Finally: by default ProjectID will refer to both the textbox holding ProjectID in the details section and the ProjectID field itself.  This ambiguity often contributes so I like to be specific like txtboxSelectedProjectID as the name of a control where I choose an id though I usually use comboboxes to select something like a project hence cmbProjectID.

Comment: DoCmd.OpenReport "ABC", acViewPreview, "", "[ID]=" & ProjectID, acNormal
DoCmd.PrintOut PrintRange:=acPages, PageFrom:=1, PageTo:=2
The above VBA is to print the document under the default condition of the printer. My goal is to select the printer first before printing the document.

Comment: You generally want a `DoCmd.SelectObject` in front of `DoCmd.PrintOut` every time you print. Having the user select which printer to use is nontrivial, you'll have to program a dialog to select a printer yourself. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/printing/retrieve-a-list-of-installed-printers and the other pages under the _printing_ tab to get started. Note this documentation is old, making it 64-bits compatible is left up to the reader.

Comment: Will you help me make an example?